# What is a `.eva` file? How is it processed to generate classes?

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

I'm inheriting an Android project.

In one java file, I have a set of imports that aren't resolving:

```
import com.gexperts.ontrack.v40.gen.entity.EMailSendRequest;
import com.gexperts.ontrack.v40.gen.entity.EMailSendResponse;
import com.gexperts.ontrack.v40.gen.entity.impl.ClientInfoImpl;
import com.gexperts.ontrack.v40.gen.entity.impl.DeviceInfoImpl;
import com.gexperts.ontrack.v40.gen.entity.impl.EMailSendRequestImpl;
import com.gexperts.ontrack.v40.gen.entity.impl.EnrolmentImpl;
```

In `/model.eva` I see the following:

```
application : com.gexperts.ontrack.v40
version: 1.0.0
author: ""
options: 
    languages: android
    feature key: asItIs

bundle gen {
    entityAspects {
        entity Enrolment {
            email: String
            password: String
        } serialization: json

        entity DeviceInfo {
            osVersion: String
            deviceType: String
            deviceModel: String
            pushId: String
            deviceId: String
        } serialization: json

        entity ClientInfo {
            revisionNumber:Integer
            timezone: String
            timezoneName: String
            locale: String
            deviceInfo: DeviceInfo
        } serialization: json

        entity EMailSendRequest {
            enrolment:Enrolment
            clientInfo:ClientInfo
        } serialization: json

        entity EMailSendResponse {
            response: String
        } serialization: json
    }
}
```

Clearly this `.eva` file needs to be processed in some way in order to generate the classes required by the import above.

How do I process this file?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: your project must be lots of fun

Comment: would it be possible that this file had been left there from your predecessor with the sole purpose of trolling you? I mean, if it was like this your project would be even more fun I think